Pine Script Fibonacii breakout signal
anyone can help me with small correction.

I want background color from 0 to 1 level in gray of Fib levels.
once 1 level broken then i want buy /sell signal depends on direction

//@version=5
indicator('ZigZag Multi Time Frame with Fibonacci Retracement', 'ZZMTF', overlay=true, max_bars_back=1000)
tf = input.timeframe(defval='', title='ZigZag Resolution')

prd = input.int(defval=5, title='ZigZag Period', minval=2, maxval=10)

showzigzag = input(defval=false, title='Show Zig Zag')
showfibo = input(defval=true, title='Show Fibonacci Ratios')

colorfulfibo = input(defval=false, title='Colorful Fibonacci Levels')

labelcol = input(defval=color.blue, title='Text Color')
fibolinecol = input(defval=color.lime, title='Line Color')
upcol = input.color(defval=color.lime, title='Zigzag Line Colors', inline='zzcol')
dncol = input.color(defval=color.red, title='', inline='zzcol')
labelloc = input.string(defval='Left', title='Label Location', options=['Left', 'Right'])

enable236 = input(defval=true, title='Enable Level 0.236')
enable382 = input(defval=true, title='Enable Level 0.382')
enable500 = input(defval=false, title='Enable Level 0.500')
enable618 = input(defval=false, title='Enable Level 0.618')
enable786 = input(defval=false, title='Enable Level 0.786')

bool newbar = ta.change(time(tf)) != 0

bi = ta.valuewhen(newbar, bar_index, prd - 1)
len = bar_index - bi + 1

float ph = na
float pl = na
ph := ta.highestbars(high, nz(len, 1)) == 0 ? high : na
pl := ta.lowestbars(low, nz(len, 1)) == 0 ? low : na

var dir = 0
iff_1 = pl and na(ph) ? -1 : dir
dir := ph and na(pl) ? 1 : iff_1
var max_array_size = 50
var zigzag = array.new_float(0)
oldzigzag = array.copy(zigzag)

add_to_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    array.unshift(zigzag, bindex)
    array.unshift(zigzag, value)
    if array.size(zigzag) > max_array_size
        array.pop(zigzag)
        array.pop(zigzag)

update_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    if array.size(zigzag) == 0
        add_to_zigzag(value, bindex)
    else
        if dir == 1 and value > array.get(zigzag, 0) or dir == -1 and value < array.get(zigzag, 0)
            array.set(zigzag, 0, value)
            array.set(zigzag, 1, bindex)
        0.

bool dirchanged = dir != dir[1]
if ph or pl
    if dirchanged
        add_to_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)
    else
        update_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)

if showzigzag and array.size(zigzag) >= 4 and array.size(oldzigzag) >= 4
    var line zzline = na
    if array.get(zigzag, 0) != array.get(oldzigzag, 0) or array.get(zigzag, 1) != array.get(oldzigzag, 1)
        if array.get(zigzag, 2) == array.get(oldzigzag, 2) and array.get(zigzag, 3) == math.round(array.get(oldzigzag, 3))
            line.delete(zzline)
        zzline := line.new(x1=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 1)), y1=array.get(zigzag, 0), x2=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 3)), y2=array.get(zigzag, 2), color=dir == 1 ? upcol : dncol, width=2)
        zzline

if not showzigzag and array.size(zigzag) >= 6
    var line zzline = na
    line.delete(zzline)
    zzline := line.new(x1=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 3)), y1=array.get(zigzag, 2), x2=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 5)), y2=array.get(zigzag, 4), color=dir == 1 ? upcol : dncol, width=2, style=line.style_dotted)
    zzline

var fibo_ratios = array.new_float(0)
var fibo_colors = array.new_color(10)
var shownlevels = 1
if barstate.isfirst
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.000)
    if enable236
        array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.236)
        shownlevels += 1
        shownlevels
    if enable382
        array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.382)
        shownlevels += 1
        shownlevels
    if enable500
        array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.500)
        shownlevels += 1
        shownlevels
    if enable618
        array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.618)
        shownlevels += 1
        shownlevels
    if enable786
        array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.786)
        shownlevels += 1
        shownlevels
    for x = 1 to 5 by 1
        array.push(fibo_ratios, x)
        array.push(fibo_ratios, x + 0.272)
        array.push(fibo_ratios, x + 0.414)
        array.push(fibo_ratios, x + 0.618)

    // set colors
    array.set(fibo_colors, 0, color.lime)
    array.set(fibo_colors, 1, color.silver)
    array.set(fibo_colors, 2, color.gray)
    array.set(fibo_colors, 3, color.red)
    array.set(fibo_colors, 4, color.purple)
    array.set(fibo_colors, 5, color.fuchsia)
    array.set(fibo_colors, 6, color.olive)
    array.set(fibo_colors, 7, color.navy)
    array.set(fibo_colors, 8, color.teal)
    array.set(fibo_colors, 9, color.orange)

var fibolines = array.new_line(0)
var fibolabels = array.new_label(0)
if showfibo and array.size(zigzag) >= 6 and barstate.islast
    if array.size(fibolines) > 0
        for x = 0 to array.size(fibolines) - 1 by 1
            line.delete(array.get(fibolines, x))
            label.delete(array.get(fibolabels, x))

    diff = array.get(zigzag, 4) - array.get(zigzag, 2)
    stopit = false
    for x = 0 to array.size(fibo_ratios) - 1 by 1
        if stopit and x > shownlevels
            break
        fibo_line_col = colorfulfibo ? array.get(fibo_colors, timenow / 1000 * x % 10) : fibolinecol
        array.unshift(fibolines, line.new(x1=math.round(array.get(zigzag, 5)), y1=array.get(zigzag, 2) + diff * array.get(fibo_ratios, x), x2=bar_index, y2=array.get(zigzag, 2) + diff * array.get(fibo_ratios, x), color=fibo_line_col, extend=extend.right))
        label_x_loc = labelloc == 'Left' ? math.round(array.get(zigzag, 5)) - 1 : bar_index
        txt = labelloc == 'Left' ? '' : '                  '
        array.unshift(fibolabels, label.new(x=label_x_loc, y=array.get(zigzag, 2) + diff * array.get(fibo_ratios, x), text=txt + str.tostring(array.get(fibo_ratios, x), '#.###') , textcolor=labelcol, style=label.style_none))
        if dir == 1 and array.get(zigzag, 2) + diff * array.get(fibo_ratios, x) > array.get(zigzag, 0) or dir == -1 and array.get(zigzag, 2) + diff * array.get(fibo_ratios, x) < array.get(zigzag, 0)
            stopit := true
            stopit





I tried my best to set the background color to gray and also to handle breakouts, but I faced many errors and couldn't get it to work.
Therefore, I need help to:
Set the background color to gray for the area between the 0 and 1 Fibonacci levels.
Generate a Buy signal if the price crosses above the 1 Fibonacci level.
Generate a Sell signal if the price crosses below the 1 Fibonacci level.
